# Not finding template when adding "tag" view

Tags: templating, users, tags

Not trying to do anything fancy here, just trying to have a "tag" view similar to my category view (which uses the same template), however, when I add my link, `/blog/{{ tag|slugify}}` (I'm using [Slugify](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/slugify) to generate a slug out of the tag name.), it returns the "Unable to find the template â€œ_layoutâ€" error. This should load the `/blog/index.html` template but it is not. My category view is working as well as the main load. (I am getting the same error when trying to do an author `/blog/{{ entry.author.username }}`) What am I missing?

Comment: As it turns out, that error was a 404 and I had an error in my `{% extends = "" %}` path. I'm still not sure why I can't get that path to return? Shouldn't I be able to list entries related to a tag vs. category vs. all on the same `/blog/index.html` template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the winner is, **routing**... Adding in [dynamic routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) got me squared away.

If the URI looks like this: `blog/*`

Load this template: `blog/index`

One thing to note (as documented in the docs), your URI should not begin with a slash (/).